# Can't get managed object context from delegate in NSURLProtocol start loading function

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a custom URLProtocol registered. When I try to get my object model context from the startloading function my app just freezes. Anyone else having this issue? 
Thanks

I have:

```
class MyURLProtocol: NSURLProtocol {
    override class function canInitWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> Bool {
        let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        return false
    }
}
```

Then in my viewDidLoad function I have:

```
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://Google.com")!)
```

Also in the AppDelegate.swift application function I have:

```
NSURLProtocol.registerClass(MyURLProtocol)
```

I'm trying to handle the request with data in my object model.

Comment: Can you describe what you're actually doing, in more detail than "try to get"?

Comment: According to your method "canInitWithRequest" definition it should return a boolean value, but you are not returning anything. First fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if I do a context.save() in the viewDidLoad function this problem goes away.